# Magento 1.9 - track id/name of last user who created/edited an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'd like to get the id/name of the last user who created/edited an order, both from the frontend or from the administration panel;

How can I get the order creator/editor 's ID/username within an observer? I am thinking about using `<sales_order_place_after>` observer; does it fire on edit or only on order creation?

### Edit:

I've already created a column in `sales/order` and `sales/order_grid` tables. As suggested I switched my observer from `<sales_order_place_after>` to `<sales_order_save_before>`. I only need the code to get the ID of the last user who edited/created the order, so I can do something like the following:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

$user_id = getUserId() ...? # <-- here is where I need your help

$order->setLastEditor($user_id);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not available with default Magento.

If you really want to see the last edited customer/admin of an order, then you need to do following things.

- Create a new column in sales/order table to save this info.
- Listen to the event `sales_order_save_before`. Make sure your observer lies inside `global` node. This is important because which will make sure your observer will get called if order is edited from either front-end side or customer side.
- In your observer, you need to set your custom column field with the id of person who is responsible for order edit/creation.

Giving a full proof solution is too-broad in nature and you should have some experience with module development in Magento in order to get it done.

### EDIT

Here I assumes you are listening to the event `sales_order_save_before`

This is how your observer should looks like

```
public function yourObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order    = $observer->getOrder();
    $editerId = false;

    //this will get customer id; works for frontend side edits
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $editerId     = $customerData->getId();
    }

    //this will get admin id; works for admin side edits
    if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        $editerId     = $customerData->getId();
    }
    
     //saves if an editor is present
    if ($editerId) {
        $order->setData('your_field_code', $editerId);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see here, we are collecting logged-in customer's id (either of customer or admin) and update it to the order. Never forget to replace `your_field_code` with your field name.

Comment: Hi Rajeev, I've already created a column in sales/order table, and I already wrote the observer that listen to `sales_order_save_before` event. I just need the code to get id of person who is responsible for order edit/creation.. can you pls help me with that?

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: thanks for your reply! anyway, what's up if there are more than 2 admins or users connected at the same time?

Comment: no problem at all. both will be in different browsers. Hence two differnt sessions and hence data will be udpated correctly. Right now you are not suspecting my codes, but you suspect how session in Magento works. :)

Comment: I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Happy to help you out and wishing you good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to answer to all your questions:

1. Once you have your `order` object in the Observer, `$order = $observer->getOrder();`you can retrieve further the Customer Id by doing `$order->getCustomerId()`
2. `<sales_order_place_after>` is triggered only on order creation.
3. The events triggered every time an order is updated are `sales_order_save_before` and `sales_order_save_after`.
4. However, using these events will not help you in finding which was the last user which edited an order (if was the creator of the order in front or if was the admin who edited that order in Admin) because Magento does not track this information. You can see in the Order Details section of Magento Admin in the `Comments History` tab some information, for example that an Invoice was created for that Order but you don't know if was related to an action that was done by the Customer or by the Admin.

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. Do you know if there's another way to get the ID/username of the last user who edited the order?